# Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 12.10 don't work on my Mac Mini

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, mac, bumblebee

I have a 2009 Mac Mini with a Core 2 Duo processor. I got fed up of MacOS so I installed Ubuntu 12.10 hoping to get some welcome relief. The "standard" (I'm not a Linux expert) drivers gave me multiple screens and proper resolution, but the image would go all wonky and pixelated at times (Techspeak. LOL). We downloaded and installed NVIDIA drivers and bumblee expecting that to solve the problem. Instead I just got the desktop icons and no dock. So we went back to the X.Org X Server drivers and now it only detects one screen and doesn't give me full resolution.

Anyone have any suggestions please?

Thanks a lot.

Tony

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.10 runs it best on nvidia 313 driver.

Do this commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
```

Then go to your additional driver page and select the nvidia 313 driver(can be that the page isn't updated, just reboot than).
Wait until the driver is installed and reboot.